# Why compiler don't prevent us, when we try to add duplicate object in Hashset?

Tags: java, exception, collections, hashset

As I know HashSet not do not take duplicate object, When I try below code it simply add first one and ignore second one.Why there is no checked Exception for this. How add() is implemented for HashSet?

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    HashSet Hs = new HashSet();
    Hs.add("A");
    Hs.add("A");
    System.out.println(Hs);
}
```

OUTPUT- [A]

Comment: Why would you expect an exception? It's not an error condition - it's simply how sets are intended to behave.

Comment: so what exactly is your question? Why *compiler* is not complaining when you add duplicated entries? Or why there is no checked exception?

Comment: @AdrianShum Don't you think it's related, you will automatically get CE if there would have been a checked exception defined for this for this condition.

Comment: @PrabhatSinghYadav No it is not.  Your title implies that "Compiler should complain if it sees duplicated entries added to a Set" (for which is quite obviously not going to happen).  And, whether there is Checked Exception depends on the design of the collection API, not the compiler.

Comment: @JonSkeet Suppose you have published that you will take only one burger a day after knowing this Someone giving you another one. I think It's an error someone doing. How do you define error?

Comment: @PrabhatSinghYadav No it is not error. Set is not "refusing to receive duplicated entries".  it is "keeping only unique entries".  Receiving same entry more than once is an expected input received by Set, and Set is ignoring input if it already exists.  You may make up your own data structure to treat duplication as error if it is something you think useful, but obviously it is not the intention of Set

Comment: @AdrianShum here you gave me something useful in above statement thanks.

Comment: Note that there's nothing stopping you from checking whether the element exists before you call `add`, or calling `add` and checking the return value.

Comment: I can kinda see why you'd want an exception, but why on earth would you want it to be a *checked* exception? That'd be completely annoying, having to wrap all calls to `add` in a try-catch block.

Answer (score 3):

The `Set` interface allows you to attempt to add the same element again and again. It will simply add the element just the first time.

It is not an error to attempt to add the same element multiple times.

> **boolean java.util.Set.add(E e)**
>
> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). **If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false**. In combination with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never contain duplicate elements.

This allows you to check if an element belongs to the `Set` and add it to the `Set` if not with a single statement:

```
if (set.add(value)) { 
    .... // will be executed only if the value was added
}
```

instead of the longer

```
if (!set.contains(value)) {
    set.add(value);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what happens internally when you pass duplicate elements in the 
>   add() method of the Set object , It will return false and do not add
>   to the HashSet , as the element is already present .So far so good .
>   But the main problem arises that how it returns false . So here is the
>   answer When you open the HashSet implementation of the add() method in
>   Java Apis that is rt.jar , you will find the following code in it.

```
public class HashSet<E>
extends AbstractSet<E>
implements Set<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;
    // Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
    private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
    public HashSet() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }
    // SOME CODE ,i.e Other methods in Hash Set
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
    // SOME CODE ,i.e Other methods in Hash Set
}
```

**So , we are achieving uniqueness in Set,internally in java  through HashMap . Whenever you create an object of HashSet it will create an object of HashMap as you can see in the italic lines in the above code .**

Answer (score 1):

When you will try to add value in set and that does not present in to the set at that time it will get added and add method will return the true,but if the value is already present in to set at that time add method will returns false.
`set.add()` method dont be supposed to give you an error when you try to add a value already in the Set,it will simply return the false.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29

Answer (score 0):

Checking the duplicate values in the set is the duty of run time but compiler. Compiler does not have any idea on the content of the set while compiling the java code. Hence you won't see any warning, suggestion, etc.

I hope this would answer your question.